# How do I set up my D7000 for auto-bracketed exposures with one shutter press?

Tags: nikon-d7000, hdr, camera-settings, bracketing

I've read that it's possible to set up the Nikon D7000to take up to 3 successive shots with different exposures using Auto Bracketing.

I've set the whole thing up on my camera, but when I press the shutter it only takes one photos opposed to three.

Does anyone know what I could be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After enabling the Auto Exposure Bracket feature, specifying the three exposure range you mentioned, use the "Interval timer shooting" option, selecting to shoot x3 photos at 1 second interval. Interval timer is located in the root level of the Shooting Menu.

1. Select Interval timer shooting menu option and press right arrow
2. Choose either "Now" as start time and press right arrow, or specify a delay time in hours/minutes before the first photo is taken
3. Using up/down and left/right arrows, set the interval between shots to 00:00:01 and press right arrow
4. At the next screen, use same up/down and left/right process and set the number of shots to "001 x 3 = 0003"
5. After you set the last number to "3" and press the right arrow once more, you will be presented with an "On/Off" prompt. Simply select on and press "OK" button to start the process

If you picked Now as the option for Step 2 above, the process will begin straight away. Otherwise, the camera will count down the amount of time specified before starting.

Note, after the interval timer is finished, the D7000 turns the interval timer function OFF. All of your previous settings like interval itself and number of shots remain, but you have to go back into the interval timer feature, use the right arrow through all the settings again until you get to the end where it asks the On/Off question.

This resetting to off is kind of a pain to me, and as a result, I have placed the entire Interval timer shooting menu as an item in the custom "My Menu" section for quicker access.

Answer (score 4):

If it is like most DSLRs, depending on which release mode you have set, you may still need to press the shutter button for each exposure. What Auto Bracketing does is automatically shifts the exposure for several successive frames. Most cameras will bracket for three exposures. The default pattern for most cameras is 0, -, + but you can customize it in some models to go -, 0, + or +, 0, -. So once you have it set up you take three pictures in succession and the camera brackets the three shots. A few cameras can be set to bracket more than three shots per series.

**For all three frames to be exposed with one shutter press, the release mode must be set to continuous low speed, continuous high speed, or self-timer. In other release modes, one shot will be taken each time the shutter-release button is pressed. It is on page 111 of the D7000 user manual.**

Comment: Which camera's have you used that required separate shutter presses for each shot in a bracket?  Every bracketing feature I've ever used has done all 3 shots for me in rapid succession.  I'm not sure what use bracketing would be if it didn't since it wouldn't capture the same thing.

Comment: Mostly Canons. A few low end Nikons. The manual for the D7000 says: "In continuous low speed and continuous high speed release modes shooting will pause after the number of shots specified in the bracketing program have been taken. Shooting will resume the next time the shutter-release button is pressed.
In self-timer mode,
the camera will take the number of shots se
lected in Step 2 on page 109 each time the
shutter-release button is pressed, regardless of the option selected for Custom Setting. In other release modes, one shot will be taken each time the shutter-release button is pressed.

Comment: I bracket successfully all the time using mirror lockup, which requires six shutter presses and three appropriate pauses to take a three shot series. It is called a tripod. :-)

Comment: true, as long as the subject isn't moving.  Good to know about single shot modes.  I never actually put my camera in single shot, so I'd never noticed that.

Comment: If the subject is moving even several fps often won't be enough to line everything up. In that case you can use layers to combine areas of varying brightness and then tone map the flattened image.

Comment: yeah, just saying that the continuous drive is helpful in making it more manageable.  It often doesn't line up exactly, but the closer you can get them the less work it is in post.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the Fn or Pv buttons to Bracketing Burst. Pressing the Fn or Pv button when Bracketing is active in single frame or quiet mode, all shots in the current bracketing program will be taken each time the shutter-release button is pressed.  Look for "Bracketing Burst" when setting the Fn or Pv buttons in the manual.

Comment: This is good when you want to bracket shots while hand-holding the camera, but is absolutely awful when the camera is tripod mounted (because you have to hold the shutter down to take all the shots).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your camera to continuous high speed drive mode.  I don't know Nikon's all that well, but I did notice that as one of the steps someone put in a guide I was able to find about your camera.  It is possible that it only auto-drives the bracketed exposures in continuous shooting mode.  From what I was reading, it sounds like it should only take one button press to shoot the entire bracket when in continuous high speed drive.